# How do I console.log every element in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble with this question related to the forEach method. I've tried every way of writing this code out that I could think of but question one is still wrong every time.

```
function exerciseOne(names){

// Exercise One: In this exercise you will be given and array called names. 

// Using the forEach method and a callback as it's only argument, console log

// each of the names.
}


// MY CODE: 

function logNames(name){

  console.log(name);
}

 names.forEach(logNames);
```

Comment: Don't post the external links. Use edit and add your code here.

Comment: This link is broken (for me at least).

Comment: Link requires a login for me

Comment: `names.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
})`

Comment: The only problem I see with your code, is that you don't implement the logic inside the `exerciseOne()` method.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you are logging the whole array. Use `forEach` method on array and log the element.

You need to pass a callback to `forEach()` the first element inside callback will be the element of array thought which its iterating. Just log that.

```js
function exerciseOne(names){
  names.forEach(x => console.log(x));
}
exerciseOne(['John','peter','mart'])
```

Arrow function may confuse you. With normal function it will be

```js
function exerciseOne(names){
  names.forEach(function(x){
    console.log(x)
  });
}
exerciseOne(['John','peter','mart'])
```

Comment: You have saved my life and i am eternally grateful!

Comment: @CodyHayes Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: console.log is a function you can do `names.forEach(console.log)`

Comment: @FareedAlnamrouti that won't work. `forEach` passes other arguments that will all get logged.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `console.log` as the callback, logging the first parameter (the current item) each time:

```js
function exerciseOne(names) {
  names.forEach(name => console.log(name));
}
exerciseOne(["Jack", "Joe", "John", "Bob"]);
```